# EWS has attachments but Attachment Collection is empty (one drive)

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app

when the email is sent from OWA browser with attachments. A link is created for attachments using one drive/sharepoint. when i tried to read the mail item from EWS the attachment collection is empty but hasAttachments flag is set to true. How do i access these attachments from EWS ?

```
EmailMessage message =  EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));

message.Attachments is empty
```

Comment: You need to show the code your using, reference attachments which is what you talking about requires that you set the requested server version to at least 2016 but you should also show the code you using the get that attachments for this to be a good question.

Comment: I added code of reading attachments. I didn't see any examples of reading reference attachments. can i just read them like regular attachments?

Comment: I've added a reference attachment sample, but something doesn't sound right you should still be getting something in the collection. if you look at the message with a MAPI editor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy do you see any attachment objects?

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example of dealing with reference attachment for this to work you need to be using the latest version of the EWS Managed API from github (the nuget version won't have the correct classes).

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016);
        service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(Token);
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("gscales@datarumble.com",adAutoDiscoCallBack);
        FindItemsResults<Item> fiResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(1));

        PropertySet psPropset = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
        psPropset.Add(ItemSchema.Attachments);

        EmailMessage Message = (EmailMessage)fiResults.Items[0];
        Message.Load(psPropset);
        foreach(Attachment Attachment in Message.Attachments)
        {
            if(Attachment is ReferenceAttachment referenceAttachment)
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + Token;
                    client.DownloadFile(referenceAttachment.AttachLongPathName, referenceAttachment.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried your code, attachments are still not coming up but still says hasAttachments true. we are using basic password authentication and the url is https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx. I also got the latest EWS dll from github. Not sure what we are missing.

Comment: I would suggest looking at a mail with a Mapi editor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy this will tell you if there are actually attachment or not

Comment: I tried EWS Editor. Attachments are not coming up when i select  "Always share them as one drive links" under Attachment preferences in OWA. they are coming up when selected "Always Attach them as copies" option . Same as what we are experiencing from our code and your sample.

Comment: The EWSEditor won't help you need to look at the item in a Mapi editor but i suspect you don't have attachment

Comment: ok I tried MFCMAPI. Attachments table is coming up in it. Not sure why it is not working from EWS. do we need 2016 for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an Exchange bug. I was able to reproduce it in OutlookSpy as well. While IMessage was showing the attachment, EWS didn't return it. OWA is using EWS in the background...

For detailed answer see: [Attachments with the ReferenceAttachment type ( ATTACH_BY_WEB_REF) from O365 mailbox are not returned using EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806240/attachments-with-the-referenceattachment-type-attach-by-web-ref-from-o365-mai)

Comment: Yes, it is. I hope they release a patch/fix for it.