# Attachments with the ReferenceAttachment type ( ATTACH_BY_WEB_REF) from O365 mailbox are not returned using EWS

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I have a mailbox on Exchange 365 and  when I share a picture from OneDrive using the **Share as OneDrive Link**, then the attachment is not returned using the latest EWS API. The list of attachments is simple empty although the HasAttachments property is true. The fallback for this type of attachment (ATTACH_BY_WEB_REF) should be a FileAttachment but the list is empty.

I did some tests with both MFCMApi and EWSEditor and here are the results:

- EWSEditor (in case when the file is shared as Onedrive Link ) is showing HasAttachment as true but when you want to load the table of attachments- it comes up empty.
  [image]
- MFCMapi- I've achieved this by adding the O365 mailbox to my Outlook profile and opening it via MFCMapi. It is showing HasAttachments as true and is able to read the attachment and it's correct ATTACH_BY_WEB_REF type
  [image]
- The Graph API correctly shows the attachment

For some reason EWS is unaware of this attachment type in some scenarios. I tried the latest EWS API and the one directly coming from Glen's github as well-with the same result (following this article: https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2015/05/working-with-referance-attachments-in.html).This was an expected result though, as his unofficial EWS managed API is adding the implementation the ReferenceAttachment. Without this the fallback type should be FileAttachment, but in my scenario there is nothing returned.

An interesting fact is that the mentioned misbehavior is happening only for O365 account and in OWA. When the email is drag and dropped to Outlook 2016 (the O365 account was opened in Outlook and the email was drag and dropped to a different mailbox on 2016 or 2019 on-prem Exchange ) then it's repaired and I'm able to read the attachments using EWS

When I add another (but regular) file attachment, then EWS returns only the file attachment, not the one shared from OneDrive.

EDIT:

OWA isn't behaving quite the regular way attachment-wise. The fact about the email containing a ReferenceAttachment is shown only in the reading pane, the Item list is not showing a preview about it:
[image]

If I add a simple FileAttachment as well to the email, then only the FileAttachment is showing up in the item list:

[image]

Looks like that OWA is using a special logic finding out about the ReferenceAttachments- maybe is analyzing the HTML body of the email which is containing info about that**OwaReferenceAttachments, OwaReferenceAttachmentDescription, OwaReferenceAttachmentFileName2**

EDIT 2:

I have uploaded the EWS Trace from an example where only one OneDrive link is in the email:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=09396538471147694985

and with 2 attachments(onedrive + file attachment):
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=82527468863185263035

Any help is appreciated here...

Comment: If you look at the EWS Trace what does the XML request look like ? Do you see that attachment in OWA okay ? (OWA is using EWS under the covers so it theory if its a bug it should reproduce in OWA)

Comment: @GlenScales- thank you for your answer.  The attachment section of the EWS Trace is completely empty. The EWS has simple no information about the ReferenceAttachment type at all. I don't understand how OWA is able to identify these types of attachments? The only information about this shared file can be found in the HTML body, which is not visible in OWA for the user. Can be that OWA is analyzing the HTML body to find out about these shared attachments? There are a lot of  html tags in the body which look like are meant for OWA:  <!--[if lte mso 15 || CheckWebRef]-->, OwaReferenceAttachments,

Comment: It might be helpful to post the trace ? what schema version for EWS are you using ? You can generally work out what EWS is doing by looking at the browser dev tools and look at the requests it makes

Comment: @GlenScales: I have edited the question and added 2 traces to 2 different emails both with OneDrive shared attachments in them

Comment: @GlenScales- do you think that this will be fixed ever? I'm in a difficult situation as there is no workaround for this in EWS at this time and we got customers complaining about missing attachments in our product. Thanks

Comment: I can't really answer that but i would suggest you (or anybody reading this having the same issue) call Microsoft support and submit it as a bug (the more people that do this the better chance it will be fixed faster especially if you can show user impact). The fact that it also impacts on OWA in some way should mean it will get fixed quicker (maybe)